# Make multiple centered images responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Here is my challenge:

I have three different sized round images (disks) that are centered within and stacked on top of each other, largest to smallest. I am now trying to have them be responsive and shrink with smaller browser windows as well as screens by staying centered within each other and shrink with the same ratio. That also means that all three images have to shrink when the window gets smaller than the largest image.

Any help is highly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div><a href=".../url1/"><img class="round1" alt="" src=".../roundimage1.png"/></a></div>
<div><a href=".../url2/"><img class="round2" alt="" src=".../roundimage2.png"/></a></div>
<div><a href=".../url3/"><img class="round3" alt="" src=".../roundimage3.png"/></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
 .round1 {
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px; 
}
.round2 {
        float: left;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        max-width: 800px;
        height: auto;
        top: 250px;
        left: 250px;
}
.round3 {
        float: left;
        z-index: 3;
        position: absolute;
        max-width: 600px;
        height: auto;
        top: 350px;
        left: 350px;
}
```

Comment: Set widths using `%` or `vw` instead. This is assuming your `html,body` styles are `100%/vw/vh`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your

```
html, body
```

is set to

```
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
```

You could do something like this (This is just an example!):

```
<div></div>
<div class="div_one"></div>
<div class="div_two"></div>

html,body{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
div{
  background:#b4d455;
  position:relative;
  height:50vh;
  width:50vw;
}

.div_one{
  background:red;
  margin-top:-20vh;
  margin-left:10vw;
}

.div_two{
  background:blue;
  margin-top:-30vh;
  margin-left:40vw;
}
```

[<kbd>Codepen</kbd>](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/GBzxr)

Then just apply it to your `div`s.

It will work with `%` too, but someone said `vw`/`vh` were cooler and they had way more stackoverflow rep than me, so I'm going to take that as fact without doing any research.